# Updating Windows 10 dual-booted alongside Ubuntu fails

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, grub, bootloader

I have a machine that is Win10/Ubuntu with the GRUB boot loader. Windows is currently trying to push an update that restarts the computer during said update, but whenever if restarts, it goes back to the GRUB loader and the installation reverts back to its previous version.

How can I allow Windows to update with the GRUB boot loader? Am I doing something wrong with the loader?

Thanks,
T

Comment: Dual booting should make no difference for the Windows update, as long as you reboot to Windows whenever needed. A question: Is it UEFI or Legacy?

Comment: You can download a Windows ISO and install from USB, but expect that you may need to repair grub afterwards (usually not difficult - see boot-repair).

Comment: @MichaelBay Legacy. It starts updating, then restarts. When I choose Windows 10, it panics and says "Restoring previous session" or something similar, and then boots into Windows without finishing the installation.

Comment: Yes, as above, install afresh and then reinstall Grub. Or, if you have UEFI, then install both OSes in the proper mode and save yourself lots of headaches like this one in the future. It's ridiculous people deliberately installing in Legacy mode where they don't have to in 2018, almost 10 years after the first UEFI PCs debuted in the market.

Comment: To repair Grub after reinstalling Windows: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows